# how to unbind all events Raphael

Tags: event-handling, raphael

The Raphael function for ex. [element.unclick(handler)](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.unclick) (which actually calls [eve.unbind(event, handler)](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#eve.unbind)) allows you remove handlers by event hanler, but how to unbind all event handlers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution with replacing the source of the raphael.js

**replace**  in line 2031

```
R["un" + eventName] = elproto["un" + eventName] = function (fn) {
    var events = this.events,
        l = events.length;
    while (l--) if (events[l].name == eventName && || events[l].f == fn) {
        events[l].unbind();
        events.splice(l, 1);
        !events.length && delete this.events;
        return this;
    }
    return this;
};
```

**with this**

```
R["un" + eventName] = elproto["un" + eventName] = function (fn) {
    var events = this.events,
        l = events.length;
    while (l--) if (events[l].name == eventName && (!fn || events[l].f == fn) ) {
        events[l].unbind();
        events.splice(l, 1);
        !events.length && delete this.events;
        return this;
    }
    return this;
};
```

so currently if handler function is not provided to unbind functions it will unbind all handler functions for that event

usage example `element.unclick();` (same for other events e.g. `element.unmouseout()`)

Answer (score 3):

This might be one way to do this.

```
Raphael.el.unbindAll = function(){
        while(this.events.length){          
            var e = this.events.pop();
            e.unbind();
        }
    }
```

and then to unbind all events of an element

```
mypath.unbindAll();
```